# dplyr: Dropping a variable from a grouped data.frame after filtering

Tags: r, dplyr

My question is pretty short. Check the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
d <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,2,2), B=c(10,11,12,13))
e <- d %>% group_by(A)
f <- e %>% filter(A==1) %>% select(-A)
f
```

This will print

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
Groups: A [1]

      A     B
  (dbl) (dbl)
1     1    10
2     1    11
```

I assumed that variable `A` would be dropped but it is not. If I would not have grouped the data before I filter and select `B` it would work.

So my question is, how can I modify the line `e %>% filter(A==1) %>% select(-A)` so that it will work? I know I could simply put a `as.data.frame()` in the chain after `filter(A==1)`. But I am curious if there is another elegant way.

Thank you very much.

Comment: use `ungroup()` before the `select`

Comment: Oh boy....thank you! :)

Comment: If you wish, you could post that as a solution and close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn, beat me to it :)

```
f <- e %>% filter(A == 1) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-A)
```

Comment: Post the same akrun?  ;)

Comment: I was working at my desk, going through the task ... and you got there :)  obviously great minds think alike :)